# Ruby on rails bootstrap css js working but not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a rails application which I added the bootstrap gem

first I added this two gems

```
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
```

which installed this packages

```
Using bootstrap 4.0.0.alpha3
Using sprockets 3.6.0
```

After I modified `application.scss` to

```
// Custom bootstrap variables must be set or import before bootstrap itself.
@import "bootstrap";
```

Then I left `application.js` like this

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
//= require_self
```

Lastly my `application.html.erb` is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Squirm</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap"  %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'partials/navbar' %>

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap seems to we working, but in the Google Chrome console seems not to be found

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading Bootstrap before you've loaded jQuery. Many of Bootstrap's components require javascript (carousel, tabs, etc.), however, most of Bootstrap will work without, which is why the Bootstrap CSS is showing on your page.

Loading Bootstrap after jQuery will fix the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Squirm</title>

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap"  %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'partials/navbar' %>

  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Also, not 100% sure based on your code, but you may be loading bootstrap twice. It seems this line: `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` is already loading Bootstrap.

Comment: thank you @AnthonyE I had two mistakes, first the order of my import, second that I was adding bootstrap twice to the project.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add jquery as well normally jquery come bundled in rails app, but maybe due to some reasons its not thr in your app

add 
jquery from

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/
```

and let us knwo if this change works.

Comment: It looks like jQuery is already being loaded in `application.js`

Comment: thank you @user5501253 you were right that jquery was in the wrong order and that was why bootstrap would not see it.